# Setting Border Inside Of the Div

Tags: html, css

How can i set the border inside of the  on the right side?

What is am trying to do is to set the border inside of the div, for that i am using the box-shadow : inset 0 0 0 10px; , but it sets the inside border on all sides.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) right/10px 100% no-repeat,
    grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

With box shadow you need to consider offest not spread:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 0 inset red;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```